# Twilio - create conference if first cal is answered

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm trying to find the best way how to achieve these:

Call a number, if answered call a second number and join both in a conference

My initial idea is to call number like in below script

```
$call = $client->calls->create(
        $from, $participant,
        array("url" => "http://myhost.com/conference.php")
    );
```

The conference.php then would be something like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>+1XXXXXXXXXX</Number>
     <Conference>Room 1234</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Do you think this will work? or what's the alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To do this, you actually want to use a combination of the REST API, to [make the second call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), and [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/) in your response.

So, your `conference.php` would look something a little like this:

```
<?
  $call = $client->calls->create(
    $from,
    $participant,
    array("url" => "http://myhost.com/conference2.php")
  );

  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Room 1234</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

And then you can make `conference2.php` just return the TwiML

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Room 1234</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: what happens if the REST API call doesn't get answered or stay busy?

Comment: That’s up to you and your app.